# Left Join Between Dates and Less Than

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have the following selection query

```
 $sql="SELECT s1.*
 FROM schedulelocation s1
 LEFT JOIN schedulelocation s2
 ON (s1.uid=s2.uid AND s1.stp>s2.stp)
 WHERE s2.stp is NULL AND s1.uid=:s1_uid AND s1.thu=:s1_thu AND s1.start<=:s1_start AND s1.end>=:s1_end";
```

Here is my data for schedulelocation (shortened version)

```
  UID      STP     start         end         Mon    Tue      Thu     Comment
 T5632      P    2015-10-06   2015-11-05       1      1       1       Hello
 U4123      P    2015-09-05   2015-10-09       1      1       1       Apple
 T5632      O    2015-10-06   2015-10-10       1      1       1       Pear
 U4123      O    2015-10-29   2015-10-31       1      1       1       Orange
```

Assuming the date is 2015-10-08 I wish to get the following answer from the query

For uid T5632  the answer "Pear"
For uid T4123  the answer "Apple"

ie the query should check that the chosen date (ie 2015-10-08) falls in between the start and end dates in the table and then chose the lowest alphabet "stp" it can. (It also has to make sure the day is thu)

The query successfully finds Pear but no results for uid T4123

Can you help me please get the answer "Apple" for U4123

EDIT - I have now tried GROUP BY

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM schedulelocation WHERE thu=:thu AND start<=:start AND end>=:end ORDER BY stp ) AS cifstp GROUP BY uid ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ORDER BY and LIMIT 1, without a join:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM
  schedulelocation s1
WHERE
  s1.uid=:s1_uid AND s1.thu=:s1_thu
  AND s1.start<=:s1_start AND s1.end>=:s1_end
ORDER BY
  stp
LIMIT 1
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea0a4/1).

**Edit**

If you want to run a single query, yes you need to use a SELF JOIN. The problem with your query is that you have to add the check of the chosen date on the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM
  schedulelocation s1 LEFT JOIN schedulelocation s2
  ON s1.uid=s2.uid
     AND s1.thu=s2.thu
     AND :datea BETWEEN s2.start AND s2.end
     AND s1.STP>s2.STP
WHERE
  :dateb BETWEEN s1.start AND s1.end
  AND s1.thu=:thu
  AND s2.uid IS NULL
```

Please see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea0a4/6).

Comment: Thanks. However I was wanting the query to run once to produce the apple and pear answers. I believe with your fiddle I need to run the query more than once for more than one UID

Comment: I have tried the GROUP BY as per my edit above. That seems to work

Comment: @user2635961 the group by is not documented, it might work on current version of MySQL but there are no guarantees that it will always work (on MariaDB it won't always work already)

Comment: Just trying your edit. Can you tell me how I make the date a varaible in this example (using PDO) ? ie the 2015-10-08?

Comment: @user2635961 i changed constant values with variables, one is :thu, the others are :datea and :dateb that contains the chosen date (both will have the '2015-10-08' value in your example)

Comment: Success . Thanks fthiella. Thats a really big help

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit naughty, but you can use `MAX()` and `MIN()` on strings...

(This should be faster than your subquery solution.  Check using `EXPLAIN`.)

```
SELECT
    s1.*,
    MIN(Comment)
FROM schedule location AS s1
WHERE
    thu = 1 AND
    start <= '2015-10-08' AND
    end >= '2015-10-08'
GROUP BY
    uid
```

Comment: Thanks Wally. Will try out

Comment: Hi. Struggling to make work. How do I select everything where you have MIN (comment). ie SELECT * MIN(comment) ? In the above answer I was using SELECT s1.* Thanks

Comment: You would need to be explicit - like you did in the answer above: SELECT s1.*, MIN(Comment) ...  You can check the performance of all answers using EXPLAIN SELECT ... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting undefined index now when I try and read the results $movedata=$mysql_link->prepare($sql);
            $movedata->execute();
     foreach($movedata->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $trains4) {
           echo $trains4['uid'];
     echo $trains4['stp'];
     echo $trains4['count'];
     }

Comment: Where's "count" defined?  Doesn't look like a field from your original post?

Comment: Okay let me check that out. Thanks again